# How to distribute ruby software?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Hi i am serching for the best way to distribute ruby software (can be open or commercial) to clients:
- with less software installed on client (only ruby interpreter)
- without less user interaction for updates

Any idea? I can use gem but it needs to install rubygems and not fit with commercial software.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend setting up a ruby project using Jeweler (http://github.com/technicalpickles/jeweler) and distributing on Gemcutter (http://gemcutter.org/) which is pretty much the standard for gem distribution.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look at [BitNami's RubyStack](http://bitnami.org/stack/rubystack) multi-platform installer if you're looking for an easy way to get Ruby, RubyGems and some common gems installed. They also make installable stacks for some common apps (e.g. Typo), but unfortunately they don't offer a way to build a custom installer for your Ruby application.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to distribute to the desktop or to a headless server?

For the desktop you could try [RubyScript2Exe](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/rubyscript2exe/) and also check out the article [Distributing Ruby Applications](http://www.erikveen.dds.nl/distributingrubyapplications/index.html)

You might also want to consider using JRuby and packaging the software as a Java application.

Comment: I am looking for a way to distribute both. And not only just a simple exe. But for example, in the Java world that can be  an application that get updated jars from a website and updates himself.